# Rebuild Lucene Search Indexes failing

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We are using Sitecore 6.5 and Lucene for searching.

I'm trying to rebuild indexes using the Index Viewer, but I'm getting an error:

> An error occurred
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Item's template is null.    at
>   Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.GetAllTemplates(Item item)

But I'm not sure how to find which item has no template...

Answer (score 2):

You've run into something that shouldn't exist inside of your sitecore database. The best way to find the item I believe is open up your SQL Management Studio and use following query on your master database:

```sql
select * from items where templateid not in (select id from items)
```

Comment: Thank you but in this case, it's on a client's machine without direct access to SQL Management studio or the SQL Server. I can get this sql executed but is there another way?

Comment: You could also just set up a DatabaseContext  and run this query directly on it!?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find it in the log depending on your logging settings. The Crawler makes a call to Item.Template which should log the template, item and database

```
if (templateItem == null)
      Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.SingleError(string.Format("Data template '{0}' not found  for item '{1}' in '{2}' database
```

Answer (score 0):

You could query the items table as mentioned, and if you dont have access to SQL server, i assume the sitecore solution is on your machine and you have the connection string?
Write a small app to run the query for you then.

```csharp
var itemIds = (from i in dbContext.items select i.id).ToList();
var orphanItems = (from oi in dbContext.items where !itemIds.Contains(i.templateId) select oi).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below given URL, I think it will solve your problem

http://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/template-item-id-not-found-for-item-pathpath/

Answer (score -1):

Just debug the index file in your project the best way to debug is

whenever you publish your site or item index automatically rebuild or the time of rebuilding the index, put the breakpoint in the index file and watch what the exact problem

here is sample code

```csharp
protected override void AddAllFields(Document document, Item item, bool versionSpecific)
{
}
```

```xml
<index id="Index name" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
   <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
   <param desc="folder">__GermanUrl</param>
   <Analyzer ref="search/analyzer" />
      <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
         <customSearch type="BusinessModul.UrlIndexer,BusinessModule">
         <Database>web</Database>
         <Root>/sitecore/content/</Root>
         <Boost>2.0</Boost>
         <IndexAllFields>false</IndexAllFields>
         <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
         <includeTemplate>template id</includeTemplate>
      </include>
   </customSearch>
   </locations>
</index>
```